# Generating a LIKE statement in Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add a like statement to an existing dynamic SQL Stored Procedure. I've tried a few different ways to implement this but can't quite get the syntax and I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing.

The Whole Statement:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetVisitListFiltered]
    @sitekey int,
    @VisitNo int = NULL,
    @DNS varchar(max) = NULL,
    @SessionStarted datetime = '1900-01-01',
    @Page varchar(max) = NULL,
    @SecondsOnSite int = NULL,
    @SecondsOnSiteRange int = NULL,
    @Pages int = NULL,
    @Cost int = NULL,
    @City varchar(max) = NULL,
    @Country varchar(max) = NULL,
    @Keywords varchar(max) = NULL,
    @Referrer varchar(max) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
        SET @SecondsOnSiteRange = 
        CASE @SecondsOnSiteRange 
        WHEN 1 THEN '='
        WHEN 2 THEN '>'
        WHEN 3 THEN '<'
        ELSE NULL
        END

        DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
            , @SQLParams NVARCHAR(MAX);

        SET @SQL = N'
            SELECT VKey,
                  VisitIP,
                  SiteKey,
                  Alert,
                  AlertNo,
                  VisitNo,
                  Invited,
                  Chatted,
                  Prospect,
                  Customer,
                  HackRaised,
                  Spider,
                  Cost,
                  Revenue,
                  Visits,
                  FirstDate,
                  TotalCost,
                  TotalRevenue,
                  OperatingSystem,
                  Browser,
                  SearchEngine,
                  Referrer + ReferrerQuery As Referrer,
                  Keywords,
                  ReferrerQuery,
                  Name,
                  Email,
                  Company,
                  Telephone,
                  Fax,
                  Street,
                  City,
                  Zip,
                  Country,
                  Web,
                  Organization,
                  CRMID,
                  Notes,
                  DNS,
                  Region,
                  FirstAlert,
                  FirstVisitReferrer,
                  ProspectTypes,
                  VisitDate,
                  SecondsOnSite,
                  Page,
                  PagesSeen
            FROM dbo.VisitDetail
            WHERE SiteKey = @p0';

        DECLARE @enddate datetime;
        SET @enddate = DATEADD(d, 1, @SessionStarted);
        SET @enddate = DATEADD(s, -1, @enddate);

        PRINT 'EndDate: ' + CONVERT(varchar(25),@enddate);

        IF NULLIF(@VisitNo, '') IS NOT NULL                                                                   SET @SQL += N' AND VisitNo = @p1';
        IF NULLIF(@DNS, '') IS NOT NULL                                                                       SET @SQL += N' AND DNS = @p2';
        IF NULLIF(@SessionStarted, '1900-01-01') IS NOT NULL                                                  SET @SQL += N' AND VisitDate BETWEEN @p3 and @p13';
        IF NULLIF(@Page, '') IS NOT NULL                                                                      SET @SQL += N' AND Page = @p4';
        IF NULLIF(@SecondsOnSite, '') IS NOT NULL AND NULLIF(@SecondsOnSiteRange, '') IS NOT NULL             SET @SQL += N' AND SecondsOnSite' + '@p12' + '@p5';
        IF NULLIF(@Pages, '') IS NOT NULL                                                                     SET @SQL += N' AND PagesSeen = @p6';
        IF NULLIF(@Cost, '') IS NOT NULL                                                                      SET @SQL += N' AND Cost = @p7';
        IF NULLIF(@City, '') IS NOT NULL                                                                      SET @SQL += N' AND City = @p8';
        IF NULLIF(@Country, '') IS NOT NULL                                                                   SET @SQL += N' AND Country = @p9';
        IF NULLIF(@Keywords, '') IS NOT NULL                                                                  SET @SQL += N' AND Keywords = @p10';
        IF NULLIF(@Referrer, '') IS NOT NULL                                                                  SET @SQL += N' AND Referrer + ReferrerQuery LIKE %@p11%';

        SET @SQLParams = N'
              @p0 INT
            , @p1 INT
            , @p2 VARCHAR(MAX)
            , @p3 datetime
            , @p4 VARCHAR(MAX)
            , @p5 INT
            , @p6 INT
            , @p7 INT
            , @p8 VARCHAR(MAX)
            , @p9 VARCHAR(MAX)
            , @p10 VARCHAR(MAX)
            , @p11 VARCHAR(MAX)
            , @p12 VARCHAR(10)
            , @p13 datetime';

        PRINT @SQL;

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
            , @SQLParams
            , @p0 = @SiteKey
            , @p1 = @VisitNo
            , @p2 = @DNS
            , @p3 = @SessionStarted
            , @p4 = @Page
            , @p5 = @SecondsOnSite
            , @p6 = @Pages
            , @p7 = @Cost
            , @p8 = @City
            , @p9 = @Country
            , @p10 = @Keywords
            , @p11 = @Referrer
            , @p12 = @SecondsOnSiteRange
            , @p13 = @enddate


    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH
```

And the specific bit I'm attempting to modify:

```
IF NULLIF(@Referrer, '') IS NOT NULL       SET @SQL += N' AND Referrer + ReferrerQuery LIKE %@p11%';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around your LIKE match. As you are generating this dynamically, you will also need to escape the quotes.

Please try the following:

```
IF NULLIF(@Referrer, '') IS NOT NULL       SET @SQL += N' AND Referrer + ReferrerQuery LIKE ''%'' + @p11 + ''%''';
```

Comment: This doesn't work - stating that @p11 is not declared

Comment: OK, I think I understand your case now : I've updated the query, could you please try again?